# can android load dll's from sdcard in native mode

Tags: android, dll, plugins, native, sd-card

I want to port a program I wrote to android. The program is in c++ on windows and linux. The program uses dll's for a plugin architecture. New plugins can be added to the program by downloading a dll which the program loads from a specific folder. 
My question is...
Is it possible to download dlls built for android to a directory on the sdcard then from native code load and use those dll's

Comment: Doesn't dll imply windows?  Don't android libraries have to be .so files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think not, external storage is mounted with option noexec. You can load libraries from app's [private directory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()).

Comment: By private directory do you mean assets and raw folders? if so I thought those were packaged with the apk. can they be downloaded to from net after install or do you have to issue a program update?..

Comment: No, I meant you should put the .so files in the directory returned from getFilesDir() method I gave you a link for. That must happen at runtime, it can be from internet or assets and raw directories

Comment: Thanks.. appreciate the answer

Comment: Technically, you can load code off the sdcard into exectuable memory, it's just that mmap will refuse to map an executable page from a noexec filesystem, so bionic's linker, which uses mmap, will refuse to do it for you - so you'd have to write your own linker which loads to anonymous mapped executable pages.  Which would be a lot of work, and mean all the code you load is using real physical memory instead of virtual memory until actually needed.